# Expressjs GET works but POST doesn't

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, http, post

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

app.get("/apis/employees", (req, res) => res.send("hello world"));
app.post("apis/employees", (req, res) => res.send("HTTP POST in action"));

const port = 3001;

app.listen(port, () => console.info(`Server is running at port ${port}...`));
```

url:

```
localhost:3001/apis/employees
```

When I try to to do a GET request using postman I will receive hello world as expected, but when
I try doing a post it says:

```
Cannot POST /apis/employees
```

I tried killing my server in the terminal and restarting it using nodemon several times, made sure I was using the right url and ports, making sure it doesn't add any additional params in the url, etc. I'm not sure why the POST request is failing.

Comment: try `/apis/employees` in `app.post`

Comment: @AksJacoves thanks, can't believe I missed that lol